# How to read "dd-mm-yyy hh:min:sec" format and extract the date - R

Tags: r, date, datetime, timestamp

The values of the column are of this type:

```
17/4/2018 02:00:00
17/4/2018 02:15:00
17/4/2018 02:30:00
```

And I need to group it by days. However, when I create a new column using as.Date() it transform it to:

```
0017-04-20
0017-04-20
0017-04-20
```

Because as.Date() assume the format is dd/mm/yyyy when in fact it is dd/mm/yyy.

How can I solve this?

PS: I tried with `as.Date(column, order=dmy)`, but it change the order for the output, not to read the input.

Comment: `as.Date('2018-05-13 12:33:44', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` works. (See [`?as.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html) and [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html).)

Comment: ... your question title has one format and your sample data has a different format ... ???

Comment: If you just want the date, you only need to specify the date part of the format: `as.Date('2018-05-13 12:33:44', format='%Y-%m-%d')`, but as r2evans points out, use `-` or `/` as it appears in your data - your question is inconsistent on this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lubridate`:

For the dates:

```
dates <- c("17/4/2018 02:00:00",
           "17/4/2018 02:15:00",
           "17/4/2018 02:30:00")

library(lubridate)
```

Use `dmy_hms()` to coerce the string to datetime, then use `as_date()` to extract the date:

```
as_date(dmy_hms(dates))
```

This returns:

```
[1] "2018-04-17" "2018-04-17" "2018-04-17"
```